# WP8 IconicTile doesn't update

Tags: windows-phone-8

In peiodic task i set iconic tile:

```
var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();
if(tile!=null)
    tile.Update(new IconicTileData{ Count= 1, IconImage=..., SmallIconImage=..., Title="test"});
```

It works, and i see "1" on tile.
After that, in mainpage of app at startap i'm trying to clear it like(without count):

```
var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();
if(tile!=null)
    tile.Update(new IconicTileData{ IconImage=..., SmallIconImage=..., Title="test" });
```

Then i exit app, but "**1**" **remains** on tile, why? No exception thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While updating the tile, if you want count not to be displayed, set count=0